Blood on this ammonia planet
I am currently building a planet that weighs about 4 earth masses and is 2.3 earth radii long. It is an ammonia planet (as the title suggests), and has ammonia oceans with some dissolved water ice, methanol, hydrazine, chlorethane, and salts (sodium, chlorides, sulfates, potassium etc.). The average temperature is about 225ºK on the planet and the avg pressure at sea level is about 4 atm.
All of my organisms require one (or more) of these three compounds for their metabolism and need to breathe them in as a result: gaseous ammonia, ethylene, and/or methane. To transport these elements, I would like to understand what cofactor would replace iron in hemoglobin to carry each of these three compounds. They should also be stable when in contact with each other, work in cells with liquid ammonia as a solvent, and work in relatively cold temperatures.
Also, as I understand, these molecules need to be broken up into radicals and transported, and then they are recombined.
Bonus points if you say what color their blood would be in each case!

carbon maybe or maybe. Though it's more likely hydrogen this stuff is easy to transfer from chemical compounds. @Neil Iyer

The planet "is 2.3 earth radii long" - "long" is not normally used to describe planets. Is it a weird shape (very difficult for a science-based answer at that mass) or are you describing the diameter (or something else)?  It may not be directly relevant, but I assume you are describing the planet for the purpose of calculating surface gravity...

Maybe that was a bit awkward but it means that the planet's radius is 2.3 times that of earth's.

@Neil Iyer that is a very big planet. Though i don't think that would change much about the blood.

Yeah, it was supposed to be a terrestrial planet so large that it is almost a mini-neptune, and I also don't think that would change much about the blood. IIRC, temperature and the gas needed to take in matters more in these kinds of situations.

@Neil Iyer as for the blood couldn't we just dissolve the gases in H2O like acid and then transport them that way?

@Fallenspacerock Maybe but the issue that the solvent is liquid ammonia, so having lots of water would probably mess up a bunch of key reactions on the planet like how having ammonia is toxic to us unless you can think of a way where the H2O doesn't interact with ammonia somehow.

@Neil Iyer It could be like certain elements in our body. We need salt to store water but to much and good night for you. So why shouldn't it be the same with this creature also it may have evolved countermeasures to keep harmful reactions from happening to much.

Check your ammonia phase diagram. I do not think you can have complex multicellular life where the life-solvent boils at the average temperature and surface pressure. Maybe make it colder.

Yeah 225 K and 4 atm seems a little better now that I think of it, so the ammonia won't just boil if the temperature changes a bit. I'll change that.

@Fallenspacerock That's a good point, so maybe that would work, but I don't know if having different cofactors is more efficient than dissolving the  and creates less side-reactions that I don't want. Water would also be ice at the average temperature/pressure that organisms have (225 K and 4 atm) so I don't know if the gases can actually dissolve also.

@Neil Iyer gasses can be acid that's why you should not breathe in certain chemicals. Though the ice may be a problem. Well then maybe we should get back to Hydrogen.

@Fallenspacerock Yeah, I'm pretty sure that I'll need a way to transport carbon and hydrogen, because gaseous ammonia could probably be transported by liquid ammonia. Going through this stack, I think iridium-based blood could work by carrying H and CH2 radicals and then recombining them into CH4 and C2H4, while  the NH3 is transported by liquid NH3. Well, I've answered my own question but I'm open to other solutions.

I'm assuming CH2 has the same charge as oxygen so that is why I am assuming it can be carried by iridium blood.

@Neil Iyer H is as far as i am concerned a really good energy source. It's very abundant and has a lot possible molecules. So it's probably the best you can get plus it can't form a solid even at absolute zero.

Recommended viewing Isaac Arthur in general and Ammonia-Based Lifeforms in particular.

On Earth, the source of energy is the oxidation of carbon compounds. Oxygen is weakly dissolvable in water so you need haemoglobin to transport it to cells. For example, you don't need any protein for CO2 transport because it dissolves well enough.  O2 is produced by plants because they need the carbon from CO2 to grow. Because haemoglobin is still bad at transporting oxygen you need to pump blood at high speed so there is enough oxygen in the body.
What is the source of those gases in the atmosphere? Why are they needed? Can those reactions be done in the lungs and then the results transported to the rest of the body?
But back to the question. Solubility increases with pressure and decreases with temperature. Additionally, lower temperatures should decrease the total rate of metabolism, making blood redundant. For example, Channichthyidae don't need it because they live in low temperatures. Additionally, this paper https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1524/zpch.1981.125.1.127/pdf claims that "The solubilities of the gases in liquid ammonia are about one order of
magnitude larger than those in water at the same temperature".
I believe you will not need any special protein to transport those gases. There will be no blood, just ammonia with some gases dissolved inside.
